# remove the last word from a cell if it's a numberin a csv file

Tags: excel, csv

I want delete the last word from a cell if it's a number like the example bellow

| header |
| --- |
| string string number1 string string number2 |
| string string number1 string string |
| string string number1 string string number2 |
| number string number1 string string |

I want to get this result

| header |
| --- |
| string string number1 string string |
| string string number1 string string |
| string string number1 string string |
| number string number1 string string |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This file shows you one way to do it](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g4FqKzcccNS2lzT_vA?e=akpJov). I presume that a word is always separated by a space. Here's a formula to place in C4 with your example in B4.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(B4,1)+0),SUBSTITUTE(B4," "&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",REPT("?", 999)), 999),"?",""),""),B4)`

Basically using reverse lookup based on being a number.